# My class implements an Interface but doesn't override it's abstract methods. Why is Eclipse still compiling it without an issue?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

```
package Myproject;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;

public class DisplayNameBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

}
```

My class DisplayNameBeanPostProcessor implements the BeanPostProcessor interface and so it must override the postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object arg0, String name) and the postProcessAfterInitialization(Object arg0, String name) methods of the interface. But even if I'm not overriding the two methods, Eclipse isn't catching the issue and it's not throwing me the expected error. Why is it so?

Comment: All methods of BeanPostProcessor are default.

Comment: Maybe a bit nitpicky but as no Spring version is mentioned in the question: only since Spring 5 all methods of BeanPostProcessor are default.

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8, default interface methods were introduced. This means your interface can provide methods with a default implementation, and they can be overridden.

All methods of BeanPostProcessor are default.
This means you are not forced to implement them, as they already have a default implementation.

Comment: So those methods in BeanPostProcessor are not abstract? I've read that interface methods are abstract and have no body, and must be overridden by a class that implements the interface.

Comment: That was the case until java 8. In java 8, this new function was added, in which you can provide a "default" implementation for interface methods. You can read more about it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-methods-java/